# Django custom templatetag: which is preferred rendering a template or populating context?

Tags: django, django-templates

I've been looking for examples of Django custom template tags and I've noticed lots of them set some values in the context instead of rendering a template.

**Which one is a better practice?**

I'll show you both examples. **In the first one**, `templatetags/entry_extras.py` populates the context in the `ContextNode`'s render method. In the template file, it loads the context calling the last_entries tag, and then it `includes` a partial template.

*extry_extras.py*

```
class ContextNode(template.Node):

    def render(self, context):
        stream = BlogEntry.objects.all()[1:5]
        context['last_entries'] = stream
        return ''

@register.tag(name="last_entries")
def get_last_entries(parser, token):
    return ContextNode()
```

*mytemplate.html*

```
...
{% load entry_extras %}
{% last_entries %}
{% include 'last_entries_widget.html' with last_entries=last_entries %}
```

**In the second example**, the template_tag renders the template itself, so in *mytemplate.html* calling the tag is enough to show the widget.

*extry_extras.py*

```
class ContextNode(template.Node):

    def render(self, context):
        stream = BlogEntry.objects.all()[1:5]
        return render_to_string('last_entries_widget.html', 
                                {'last_entries': stream},
                                context)

@register.tag(name="last_entries")
def get_last_entries(parser, token):
    return ContextNode()
```

*mytemplate.html*

```
...
{% load entry_extras %}
{% last_entries %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second one is very poor practice. Django has a built-in way to render a template from a tag: use an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). You should definitely do that rather than rendering the template yourself.

Actually, Django now has a built-in way of setting variables in the context as well: [assignment tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags). Again, you should use this. I think in the 8 years I've been using Django I've maybe written a full Node class/tag function once, versus hundreds of functions using the decorator shortcuts.

As to which you should use, it very much depends on what you want to achieve. I would say, though, that setting variables in the context only to use them in an include seems very weird: again, that is *exactly* what the inclusion tag is for.